# how to select the first element from a dropdown. RoR/Capybara/Selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, capybara

So this code was working perfectly fine, until I recently updated my selenium webdriver:

```
When /^I search for (.*)$/ do |term|
    term = " " if term == "blank"
    step "I fill in search with #{term}"
    within(".navbar-search") do
        page.find(:css, "li:first").click
    end
end
```

I updated, and now I get the following error:

```
 An invalid or illegal string was specified (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
  ./features/step_definitions/search_steps.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  ./features/step_definitions/search_steps.rb:4:in `/^I search for (.*)$/'
  features/search_friend.feature:13:in `When I search for <term>'
```

Here is the cucumber feature:

```
@javascript
Scenario Outline: The search bar
    Given I login
    And I have a contact named ABC
    And I have a contact named DEF
    And I have a contact named GHI
    When I search for <term>
    Then I should see the message <message>

    Examples:
    | term | message |
    | ... some examples ... | |
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess you updated not only Webdriver but also Capybara.

[Capybara 2.1 now uses driver's implementation of CSS selectors](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/961). In case of Selenium Webdriver it means that browser's implementation is used. `:first` pseudo selector is not standard and isn't supported by browsers so your CSS selector is not valid.

Previously it worked because Capybara converted CSS selector to XPath using Nokogiri. Nokogiri supports `:first` pseudo selector.

So you should change your invalid CSS selector to something valid like:

- `page.first(:css, 'li').click`
- `page.find(:css, 'li', match: :first).click` (the difference between previous variant and this one is that this variant waits for element to appear on the page but the first one doesn't wait. See [this section of Capybara README](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#strategy) to get more information on `match`)
- `page.find(:css, "li:first-child").click`
- `page.find('li:first-child').click`

Comment: first option didn't work, second one did. Thank you very much.

Comment: @wachichornia I guess first variant doesn't work as it doesn't wait for element to appear on the page. Is my guess correct?

Comment: it doesn't find it, which means effectively that it doesn't wait. You're correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out! It took me ages to find why it didn't work